# MySite Migration

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, mysites, content-migration

I'm working on a SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 migration.  Initially, we weren't going to migrate mysites and just create a new one.  After the migration it became clear that some people were using a lot of stuff on their old mysite and they wanted it back.

We've already created the managed metadata and UPS for the new site.

How can I migrate the old MySites into the new one? Should I scrap the MM & UPS and start over with a proper MySite upgrade or can I back up and restore the old sites to the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your mysite url will be same in both farms( 2010 & 2013), as you moved everything in the 2013.

One thing, keep in mind, backup & restore method between 2010 & 2013 not supported. You have to do the Database move operation.

Before upgrading the My Site Host and the personal site collections, you must upgrade the Managed Metadata service application, and then the User Profile Service application. If you already upgraded those then no issue. Please see below technet for more information.

[Upgrade My Sites to SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479424.aspx)

Comment: I created a brand new SP 2013 farm and created the MM and UPS service applications already.  I didn't upgrade them from 2010.  Are you saying that's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to recreate the MM and UPS services to do this.

**First Approach:**

MySite is actually a site collection so you can backup and restore for each user who claimed. But i believe it will still point to the old SharePoint 2010 URLs (if any) because Backup-Restore method will simple put the old site on new one. If there is no such a customization's on MySites you can backup and restore which should work fine.

**Second Approach:**
 You can export and import the MySite (root site) as it will re-point the URL's to new SharePoint 2013.

Regards